# How to check if all characters of a string appear in another string in order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to check if a word is a valid abbreviation of another word. To be valid, all letters in the abbreviation must appear in the original word, in order.

For example:

- 'Msttum' *is* an abbreviation of 'Darmstadtium'
- 'Amsi' *is not* an abbreviation of 'Samarium'

How can I do this?

Comment: What about `a.lower() in b.lower()`

Comment: That doesn't check if they are in order. It would yield True for 'Amsi', 'Samarium'.

Comment: Not sure why you think that. Have you tried it?

Comment: OK, so it yields False for Samarium, but it also yields False for Darmstadtium.

`if sym.lower() not in el.lower():
        a = False
        return a`

Comment: It only gives us True if the letters are in the word consecutively.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution:

```
def is_abbrev(word, abbrev):
    it = iter(word.lower())
    return all(x in it for x in abbrev.lower())
```

For example:

- `is_abbrev("Hello", "hell")` => `True`
- `is_abbrev("Hello", "hLl")` => `True`
- `is_abbrev("Hello", "llh")` => `False`